# Delete an altChunk

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

How can I successfully delete an altChunk with a given id from a document. The process that I'm following is -

```
MainDocumentPart mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart;
mainPart.DeletePart(mainPart.GetPartById("AltChunkIdA1"));
```

I'm adding the altChunk after a given sdt. For adding an altChunk, I've the following code -

```
string altSchedChunkId = "AltChunkIdA1";
AlternativeFormatImportPart schedChunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altSchedChunkId);
schedChunk.FeedData(File.Open(FileA12, FileMode.Open));
            AltChunk altSchedChunk = new AltChunk();
            altSchedChunk.Id = altSchedChunkId;

            OpenXmlElement parent = sdtRunSchedTerms.Parent;
            parent.InsertAfter(altSchedChunk, sdtRunSchedTerms);
```

But it doesn't seem to work out. Instead of the altChunk getting deleted, a new altChunk with the same id is added every time I try editing the document.

Thanks in advance,

Neha

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with chunks, but I think I solved it.

If you look carefully at the code to add a chunk, you see that it actually does two things:

1. create a chunk (`AddAlternativeFormatImportPart`)

and

2. add a reference to the chunck somewhere in the document (`InsertAfter`).

The code in which you delete the chunk does not delete the reference to the chunk. If you then add a new chunk with the same id *and* add a reference, you will end up with your chunk appearing twice.

See [AltChunk class documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk.aspx) for more details.

I use this code to remove any existing references to a chunk.

```
var altChunks = mainPart.RootElement.Descendants<AltChunk>().Where(e => e.Id == altChunkId);

foreach (var altChunk in altChunks)
{
    altChunk.Remove();
}
```

After that, you can use `DeletePart()` to delete the chunk itself.

I must admit that I found this by trial and error, so I am not 100% sure it is the recommended way to do it, but it appears to work.

To get a better feeling about what a chunk actually is, I unzipped a .docx-file ([7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is willing to do this) and found a directory *word* which contains chunks, as well as a directory *_rels* with a file *document.xml.rels* inside. The latter lists the references to the chuncks, i.e. where they should be inserted.